1st order sigma delta output is wrong verilog
I have done a 1st order sigma delta below is my code:
module sigma_delta_1st_order #(
    localparam  adder_width  = 10
)( clk, i_rst_an, frac_input, otw_f );
    input clk, i_rst_an;
    input [adder_width:0] frac_input;
    output otw_f;

    reg [adder_width:0] output_dff;
    wire [adder_width+1:0] output_adder;


    initial begin
        output_dff <= 'd0;
    end

    assign  otw_f = output_adder[adder_width+1];
    assgin output_adder = output_dff + frac_input;

    always @(posedge clk or negedge i_rst_an) begin
        if(~i_rst_an) begin
            output_dff <= 'd0;
        end
        else begin
            output_dff <= output_adder[adder_width:0];
        end
    end
endmodule

As input I feed a static 0.2*2**11 (fractional to binary) & Fclock = 1.2GHz
the MSB of the output of sigma delta (otw_f[11] in this example) I feed it to a LPF with a cut off ~= 150kHz
and the output of the sigma delta is:

something I presume have not done right, because the average value should have been the 0.2 I changed the number of bits to 21 for example and still not a change, which is strange the Clock is 1.2GHz which is very high.

You seem to have repeated the first three lines; I've deleted one repetition to fix the file's validity.

thanks i also edited some part of the code thansk

have your tried modeling your algorithm in Matlab or Octave first?

What is the weight of the MSB? We don't know exactly how you performed the conversion from bit to Volts.
Furthermore, the output you show us is the DAC output after some kind of analog filtering, right?

yes it worked in matlab.
is 1 bit, output of mash, the output of the mash -> I put it as an input to an passive RC filter 1st order to get the mean value, nothing fancy
